ValueError while saving a dataframe
I am facing hurdle while saving a pandas data frame to parquet file
Code I am using -
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start_date = "2022-08-06"
end_date = "2024-08-05"

ticker = 'RELIANCE.NS'
data = yf.download(tickers=ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date, interval="1h")

data.reset_index(inplace=True)

data['Date'] = data['Datetime'].dt.date
data['Time'] = data['Datetime'].dt.time

data.to_parquet('./RELIANCE.parquet')

The error it produces is - ValueError: Can't infer object conversion type: 0
Can someone tell me how to fix this.
PS: Detailed error below-
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 15
     12 data['Date'] = data['Datetime'].dt.date
     13 data['Time'] = data['Datetime'].dt.time
---> 15 data.to_parquet('./RELIANCE.parquet')

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:333, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    327 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    328     warnings.warn(
    329         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    330         FutureWarning,
    331         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    332     )
--> 333 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3113, in DataFrame.to_parquet(self, path, engine, compression, index, partition_cols, storage_options, **kwargs)
   3032 """
   3033 Write a DataFrame to the binary parquet format.
   3034 
   (...)
   3109 >>> content = f.read()
   3110 """
   3111 from pandas.io.parquet import to_parquet
-> 3113 return to_parquet(
   3114     self,
   3115     path,
   3116     engine,
   3117     compression=compression,
   3118     index=index,
   3119     partition_cols=partition_cols,
   3120     storage_options=storage_options,
   3121     **kwargs,
   3122 )

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py:480, in to_parquet(df, path, engine, compression, index, storage_options, partition_cols, filesystem, **kwargs)
    476 impl = get_engine(engine)
    478 path_or_buf: FilePath | WriteBuffer[bytes] = io.BytesIO() if path is None else path
--> 480 impl.write(
    481     df,
    482     path_or_buf,
    483     compression=compression,
    484     index=index,
    485     partition_cols=partition_cols,
    486     storage_options=storage_options,
    487     filesystem=filesystem,
    488     **kwargs,
    489 )
    491 if path is None:
    492     assert isinstance(path_or_buf, io.BytesIO)

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py:349, in FastParquetImpl.write(self, df, path, compression, index, partition_cols, storage_options, filesystem, **kwargs)
    344     raise ValueError(
    345         "storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path"
    346     )
    348 with catch_warnings(record=True):
--> 349     self.api.write(
    350         path,
    351         df,
    352         compression=compression,
    353         write_index=index,
    354         partition_on=partition_cols,
    355         **kwargs,
    356     )

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py:1304, in write(filename, data, row_group_offsets, compression, file_scheme, open_with, mkdirs, has_nulls, write_index, partition_on, fixed_text, append, object_encoding, times, custom_metadata, stats)
   1301 check_column_names(data.columns, partition_on, fixed_text,
   1302                    object_encoding, has_nulls)
   1303 ignore = partition_on if file_scheme != 'simple' else []
-> 1304 fmd = make_metadata(data, has_nulls=has_nulls, ignore_columns=ignore,
   1305                     fixed_text=fixed_text,
   1306                     object_encoding=object_encoding,
   1307                     times=times, index_cols=index_cols,
   1308                     partition_cols=partition_on, cols_dtype=cols_dtype)
   1309 if custom_metadata:
   1310     kvm = fmd.key_value_metadata or []

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py:904, in make_metadata(data, has_nulls, ignore_columns, fixed_text, object_encoding, times, index_cols, partition_cols, cols_dtype)
    902     se.name = column
    903 else:
--> 904     se, type = find_type(data[column], fixed_text=fixed,
    905                          object_encoding=oencoding, times=times,
    906                          is_index=is_index)
    907 col_has_nulls = has_nulls
    908 if has_nulls is None:

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py:122, in find_type(data, fixed_text, object_encoding, times, is_index)
    120 elif dtype == "O":
    121     if object_encoding == 'infer':
--> 122         object_encoding = infer_object_encoding(data)
    124     if object_encoding == 'utf8':
    125         type, converted_type, width = (parquet_thrift.Type.BYTE_ARRAY,
    126                                        parquet_thrift.ConvertedType.UTF8,
    127                                        None)

File ~/python_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py:357, in infer_object_encoding(data)
    355     s += 1
    356 else:
--> 357     raise ValueError("Can't infer object conversion type: %s" % data)
    358 if s > 10:
    359     break

ValueError: Can't infer object conversion type: 0       2022-08-08
1       2022-08-08
2       2022-08-08
3       2022-08-08
4       2022-08-08
           ...    
3398    2024-08-02
3399    2024-08-02
3400    2024-08-02
3401    2024-08-02
3402    2024-08-02
Name: Date, Length: 3403, dtype: object


Your code worked for me without any issues. I assume this issue is arising from the parquet engine that you are using to save the file as parquet( io.parquet.engine, pyarrow or fastparquet).
Here are the versions of the libraries I have used:
Pandas version: 2.2.2
PyArrow version: 16.1.0

To make sure you are using pyarrow or any desired engine make sure you include it like this:
data.to_parquet('./RELIANCE.parquet', engine='pyarrow')

Here's first two rows of the saved parquet file:
{"Datetime":1659930300000,"Open":2532.25,"High":2572.75,"Low":2531.39990234375,"Close":2569,"Adj Close":2569,"Volume":0,"Date":"2022-08-08T00:00:00.000Z","Time":33300000000}
{"Datetime":1659933900000,"Open":2568.60009765625,"High":2571,"Low":2562.10009765625,"Close":2567.300048828125,"Adj Close":2567.300048828125,"Volume":392815,"Date":"2022-08-08T00:00:00.000Z","Time":36900000000}

If you would not consider changing your parquet engine, you should investigate what data type conversions might go wrong. As an example you can try converting time to string.

This error you've encountered could be from the 'Datatime' column in your DataFrame (df) which contains timezone information that the 'to_parquet' function can't handle properly. Try inserting the code below to the end of your script to convert the 'Datetime' column to a timezone-naive datetime format before saving it to Parquet.
    # Previous code
    
    data.reset_index(inplace=True)
    
    # Ensure 'Datetime' column is timezone-naive
    data['Datetime'] = data['Datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)
    
    data['Date'] = data['Datetime'].dt.date
    data['Time'] = data['Datetime'].dt.time
    
    data.to_parquet('./RELIANCE.parquet')`


Looking through pandas repository (for reference) - I'd say it's issue with mixed types. Likely 0 will refer to first column from the left.
As an exercise I'd try:
data[data.columns[0]] = data[data.columns[0]].astype("str")
data.to_parquet(...)

otherwise casting all columns to string should work, but you should be able to narrow down which one is a trouble maker.
As a side note - with parquet these are recognized data types - so your dataframe ideally would contain only these prior to saving. There's some degree that can be handled using saving engine, but in general - if you cast types yourself - you will be more explicit.
